# Merge Sort Base Case

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

I'm practicing sorting algorithms and I'm stuck on this silly issue.

[image: hackerearth]

I specifically don't understand how the array is partitioned to arrays that only contain single (sorted) element. I drew out a call stack example to illustrate my confusion.

```
void merge_sort(int A[], int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        int mid = (start + end ) / 2;
        merge_sort(A, start, mid);                 
        merge_sort(A, mid + 1, end);
        merge(A, start, mid, end);   
    }                    
}
```

the call stack should look something like this

merge_sort(A,0,5) A [9,7,8,3,2,1]

merge_sort(A,0,2) A [9,7,8]

merge_sort(A,0,1) A [9,7]

merge_sort(A,0,0) -> here the base case would fail, no?

in which case the array would not get partitioned into singleton arrays.

Comment: Okay, but inside the if block, there is the merge function. if it start == end, so start < end will get skipped, nothing will get merged, and I'll be left with the previous call which is A[9,7] which is not a singleton array.

Comment: Do you have a program that performs the merge sort correctly?  If so, why not step through it with a debugger to clear all doubts as to what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `start == end` it means there's only a single element to "sort".

And since `start == end` also means that `start < end` will be false, then from that follows that the function skips everything inside the `if` body.

So `merge_sort(A,0,0)` doesn't do anything, but return back up the call-stack to `merge_sort(A,0,1)` .

---

Looking at the `merge_sort(A, 0, 1)` call specifically it looks like this:

```
merge_sort(A, 0, 1)
    merge_sort(A, 0, 0)  // Does nothing
    merge_sort(A, 1, 1)  // Does nothing
    merge(A, 0, 0, 1)    // Merge the two partition 0-0 with 1-1
```

So once `merge_sort(A, 0, 0)` returns (without doing anything) then `merge_sort(A, 1, 1)` is called which again does nothing but return. Anmd then the two sub-arrays are "merged" with `merge(A, 0, 0, 1)`.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. It get's returned to merge_sort(A,0,1) which is not what it's supposed to do. It should first partiton everything into singleton arrays and then start merging, i don't see how this occurs here.

Comment: @Vocaloidas But when `start == end` then there is only ***one single element*** to sort. In the example of `merge_sort(A, 0, 0)` that single element is `A[0]`. How do you partition a single element further?

Comment: You don't, but at that point it should start calling the merge function to begin constructing a new sorted array. It can't do that if the merge function is inside the if block and it cannot enter that if block.

Comment: @Vocaloidas I've updated my answer. The `merge` call happens in `merge_sort(A, 0, 1)`, not in `merge_sort(A, 0, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive call to `merge_sort(A,0,0)` returns immediately because `left == right` ie: a slice with a single element.

Comment: I don't quite follow, returns what? No other function get's executed i.e. to merge them because it will fail the base case. Then I'm left with the A[9,7] which is not a singleton array.

Comment: @Vocaloidas: `merge_sort(A,0,1)` first calls `merge_sort(A,0,0)`, then `merge_sort(A,1,1)`, then merges the 2 1-element subslices, as explained by Someprogrammerdude.

Answer (score 0):

Base case would return cause start == end and not start < end